# Windows 10 : Chrome headless not doing anything

Tags: google-chrome-devtools

When entering the following command in Windows 10 and start a headless chrome version, nothing is happening (with/without extensions):

```
"c:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" 
      --disable-extensions --headless --disable-gpu --print-to-pdf
```

It just returns to the command line silently and I can't find any pdf file.

Does anybody had the same issue and manage to solve it ?

I'm using : Google Chrome   63.0.3239.84 (Official Build) (64-bit) (cohort: 63_win_84)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Headless Chrome to print pdf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46074235/headless-chrome-to-print-pdf)

Answer (score 9):

It looks like Chrome doesn't have rights to write in the directory.
Try to launch command with --enable-logging flag. Like:
`"c:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" 
      --enable-logging --disable-extensions --headless --disable-gpu --print-to-pdf`
You will receive an error. Fix it and it will start to work.
You can find more information here:
[How do I use Headless Chrome in Chrome 60 on Windows 10?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45364102/how-do-i-use-headless-chrome-in-chrome-60-on-windows-10)

Comment: That's working, got [1224/095554.741:ERROR:headless_shell.cc(530)] Writing to file output.pdf was unsuccessful, could not open file: FILE_ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED

Comment: after adding the location it works, great. --print-to-pdf=c:\temp\output.pdf. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

chrome needs full path also.

To use it in cmd.exe:

```
start chrome --enable-logging --headless --disable-gpu --print-to-pdf=%cd%\output.pdf https://www.google.com/
```

Answer (score 0):

I was experiencing this problem.

My solution was to go and download the Canary Build for Chrome.
https://www.google.com/chrome/browser/canary.html

This will then get installed to C:\User\userName\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome SxS\Application. Try running your commands pointing to this install.