# headless chrome not working in windows 10

Tags: windows, google-chrome, pdf, google-chrome-headless

i trying to convert a sample HTML file to PDF using headless chrome and it is not working in windows 10.

this is the command i am using to convert the file,

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --headless --disable-gpu --print-to-pdf=t.pdf t.html
```

the content in my html file is below,

```
<html>
<head>
<title>test</title>
</head>
<body>
<p>this is the sample file</p>
</body>
</html>
```

I have also tried for google.com and it is not working.

Also, I have noticed that after running this command it is creating 6 chrome processes under CMD in task manager,

[image]

Can someone help me in solving this issue. I have already checked the below question but none helped -

[SO Link 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45364102/how-do-i-use-headless-chrome-in-chrome-60-on-windows-10)

[SO Link 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46077392/additional-options-in-chrome-headless-print-to-pdf)

[Super User](https://superuser.com/questions/592974/how-to-print-to-save-as-pdf-from-a-command-line-with-chrome-or-chromium)

Comment: To me it looks like you are trying to write output in Program Files. Maybe permissions?

Comment: You could have a look at ABCpdf which uses a customised headless Chrome engine. It also enables some funky javascript extensions: https://www.websupergoo.com/abcpdf-html-to-pdf-conversion.aspx

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59047134/chrome-driver-headless-option-is-not-working-for-link
you may find solution in this link

Answer (score 0):

how about

```
 start chrome --headless --disable-gpu --print-to-pdf=%cd%\t.pdf t.html
```

?