# chrome driver headless option is not working for link?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, google-chrome-headless

--headless option is not working for some link I don't know why but working for other links.
Need of headless is I have to run this crawler on AWS instance which must required headless approch(No GUI)..
link= https://shop.nordstrom.com/s/pj-salvage-animal-lover-pajama-top-plus-size/5405170/full?origin=category-personalizedsort&breadcrumb=Home%2FWomen%2FClothing&color=charcoal

**Using Headless Option**

```
#for head less approch
options = Options()
options.binary_location = "/Applications/Google\ Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google\ Chrome"
options = Options()
options.add_argument("start-maximized")
options.add_argument('--headless')
options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
options.add_argument("--hide-scrollbars")
options.add_argument("disable-infobars")
options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')
options.add_argument("window-size=1920,1080")

prefs = {
    "translate_whitelists": {"fr": "en", "de": "en", 'it': 'en', 'no': 'en', 'es': 'en', 'sv': 'en', 'nl': 'en',
                             'da': 'en', 'pl': 'en', 'fi': 'en', 'cs': 'en'},
    "translate": {"enabled": "true"}
}
options.add_experimental_option("prefs", prefs)
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
#################################################################################

driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
```

Comment: which version of chromedriver you are using?

Comment: i'm using linux but dont know which chromedriver version

Comment: tell ma how to check

Comment: If chrome driver installed globally then this command will work chromedriver -v

Comment: Download the latest version of chrome from here https://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads

Comment: ChromeDriver 2.41.578700 (2f1ed5f9343c13f7f15c00b370eda6706)

Comment: This version of chrome is too old. Download the latest version of chromedriver and replaced it from your binary path

Comment: How? i dont know how to setup please guide me... i just follow setups form internet

Comment: and i want to install this driver in AWS instance i have only ternimal access...so guid me

Comment: I have updated my comment please check it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After searching a lot i notice those web-sites which send JS code first they have problem in opening in headless argument so i come up with solution to use virtualDisplay ..

Run this command in terminal or windows cmd or power-shell to install this

```
apt-get -y install xvfb    
pip install PyVirtualDisplay
pip install xvfbwrapper
```

and this is the code you need to put in your code

```
from pyvirtualdisplay import Display
display = Display(visible=0, size=(800, 600))
display.start()
```

after you code in the end

```
display.stop()
```

Answer (score 1):

As the latest version of chromedriver(**After ChromeDriver 79.0.3945.16**) fixed the issue element not clickable on headless mode.

Download the latest version of chromedriver.Hopefully your problem will be solved.

**Here is the Changelog**

- Fixed ChromeDriver crash caused by javascript alert fired during command execution
- Fixed a bug causing Chromedriver to lock when an alert is fired while
  taking a screenshot
- Removed --ignore-certificate-errors from Chrome launch command
     Changed platform and platformName to windows on Win10
- Fixed undefined window.navigator.webdriver when "enable-automation"
  is excluded
- Fixed WPT test "test_not_editable_inputs[hidden]"
- **Fixed "Element is not clickable" when using headless mode**

**Chromedriver changelog and download link**
https://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads

**EDITED**
For aws You need to follow these steps

First, you need to install chrome using the following steps

```
sudo curl -sS -o - https://dl-ssl.google.com/linux/linux_signing_key.pub | apt-key add
sudo echo "deb [arch=amd64]  http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main" >> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list
sudo apt-get -y update
sudo apt-get -y install google-chrome-stable
```

Then Download chromedriver

```
wget https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=79.0.3945.16/
unzip chromedriver_linux64.zip
```

Now add permission and move binary file

```
sudo mv chromedriver /usr/bin/chromedriver
sudo chown root:root /usr/bin/chromedriver
sudo chmod +x /usr/bin/chromedriver
```

For opening chrome change the binary path `options.binary_location` 
 and add argument `options.add_argument('--headless')`

NB: Do not forget to install java

Comment: and how to install this driver in AWS instance... i have only terminal access..

Comment: Follow the steps now

Comment: I'll try and let you know.Thanks for the time being

Comment: This is show Error msg and i have install latest chrome-driver:
`Message: session not created: This version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 79`

Comment: and what will be the binary_location in options.binary_location ?

Comment: Yes this is the binary location..

Try this file using 
wget https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=79.0.3945.36/

Comment: now the problem is this latest chrome driver only run with latest google-chrome so now how i can update google-chrome..

Comment: sudo apt-get --only-upgrade install google-chrome-stable

Comment: Check google chrome version 
google-chrome --version

Comment: I have the updated version of chrome..(78.0.3904.108-1)

Comment: my problem is not get solve by updating chromedriver